# Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have an  array:

```
w = np.array([1,  2,  3])
```

and I need to create a Dataframe with a MultiIndex looking like this:

```
df=  0  1  2
0 0  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
  2  1  1  1
1 0  2  2  2
  1  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2
2 0  3  3  3
  1  3  3  3
  2  3  3  3
```

How can i assign the values of my array to the correct positions in the DataFrame?

Comment: The input is only `w` or do you also have a preexisting single-indexed dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

The exact logic is unclear, by assuming `w` is the only input and you want to broadcast it as index(0,1) and columns:

```
w = np.array([1,  2,  3])

N = len(w)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(w, N**2).reshape((-1,N)),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(N)]*2)
                  )
```

output:

```
     0  1  2
0 0  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1
  2  1  1  1
1 0  2  2  2
  1  2  2  2
  2  2  2  2
2 0  3  3  3
  1  3  3  3
  2  3  3  3
```

Comment: this is helping and getting me foreward! I need to find good sources to learn how to transform DataFrames, have you any suggestions for me?

Comment: Try, fail, read the docs, search stackoverflow, try again, succeed ;)